# How to enable tabbing through a select field in an Antd form?

Tags: reactjs, antd

By default with AntD forms when tabbing through fields and coming across a Select field, the user inputted value doesn't stay when tabbing to the next field. How do I fix that? I've been trying various ways of using onBlur to set the Select field when the user tabs out of it but can't get it to work.

I created a simple codesandbox here to illustrate my problem.

CodeSandBox [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-form-select-problem-n2uvn?file=/src/MyForm.js)

For example to reproduce what i'm referring to..

1. input something into the first input field and then hit tab to move focus to the second input field (the select dropdown).
2. input one of the options using the keyboard such as "A".

[image]

3. Tab to the third field. Note the second field (the Select dropdown) doesn't stay populated with the inputted value. The only way to get it to stay is to use your mouse to select it. Which isn't a good user experience.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the normal behavior of antd. It doesn't stay because the `Select` has no value and even you type the exact value and hit the tab it will not stay because it has no value, you need to select in options list in order the input to stay. The purpose of the search is to select an option quickly, not setting the value on the `Select`

One solution is to make the `Select` to be a controlled component, meaning the value will be based on state value:

```
this.state = {
  ...
  second: undefined,
}

onSearch = (value) => {    
  if (value.trim()) {
    this.setState(() => ({ second: value.toUpperCase() }));
  }
};

<Select
  value={this.state.second}
  onSearch={this.onSearch}
>
```

[image: Edit prod-http-h73fi]

Beware that this is not the better approach, the user can type anything to it even the input was not on the option list. I suggest to look on antd component called `Autocomplete`. You can achieve the same goal but a good choice if you allow the user to type in to it even the input is not in the option list.

Comment: Getting error in this sandbox demo.